#  bridge language between PHP and Objective-C

Tags: php, iphone

i want to show php page in iphone application. I have also used  webview to display page but not able to know how to apply slide effect on page please help me...

i am working with one application in which i m working with php listing page and then i want to show detail page but how to show slide transition effect.

Comment: i am working with one application in which i m working with php listing page and then i want to show detail page but how to show slide transition effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP page itself is not able to produce any kind of animation on iphone. If you want to use slide effect or any other animation/effect use jQTouch framework or jQuery mobile framework. They have very simple js methods to produce lots of effects.